# Is it possible to have a MYSQL field that always is equal to another?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using some code written for once place in another, which I guess is the start of my problems.

In my ideally unchangeable existing code I have a query something like:

```
SELECT username FROM users
```

However, in the new database, there is no username field, but there is an email address.

I'd like to change the new database somehow so that when I ask for username I get back the email.

I understand that I can just make a new field and manually populate it when the email updates, but I'd really like some kind of alias so that both codebases can work without modification.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_users AS
SELECT email AS username
FROM users
```

Since this is over just one table, you could even use it for updates and inserts as well as queries (if you are using a relatively new version of MySQL)

You could even create all the views in a separate database - that way they could have the same names as the original tables:

```
CREATE VIEW db2.users AS
SELECT email AS username
FROM db1.users
```

Answer (score 4):

You could add the `username` field and keep it aligned to the e-mail address through a trigger, or you could use a view of the `users` table.

Triggers: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-trigger.html

Views: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support Computed Columns.
There are a few workarounds from what I found when googling this matter, but you're probably best off just copying the values, or using a trigger which automatically updates it.

Comment: A workaround like a view, perhaps? Plus, adding a computed column or a trigger or a new column for a trigger to update constitutes changing the original schema, which the OP specifically doesn't want to do.